# two different cursors in different elements in a same page

Tags: html, css

I can't use two cursors in a page on the different elements can anyone help me why is happening?

```css
    .c-scrolldown{
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .c-scrolldown2{
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

```html
<div class="c-scrolldown2" id="pointer-cursor">
     <div class="c-line2"></div>
</div>
<div class="c-scrolldown">
     <div class="c-line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what you **want** to happen, and what currently **is** happening. Your code looks a little sparse so also please give some context as well.

Comment: btw, you have the same pointer defined in the css for both the elements... and you are talking about two different

Comment: i cant use two cursors in different div, what do i explain in this.

Comment: You can only focus on one element at a time so the cursor will only be wherever you have focused.  Perhaps you should refresh yourself with [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you cannot see what is wrong with the above question.   If you continue to ask poor quality and downvoted questions, you will get a [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Answer (score 3):

Just add some content inside divs  and change cursor that you need.

```css
.c-scrolldown{
   cursor: pointer;
}
.c-scrolldown2{
   cursor: progress;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-scrolldown2" id="pointer-cursor">
    Test 1 
    <div class="c-line2"></div>
</div>
<div class="c-scrolldown">
    Test 2 
    <div class="c-line"></div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) you can find a bunch of different mouse cursors.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.
 You just need either some content or a defined height for your DIVs (in your code the DIVs have zero height):

```css
.c-scrolldown,
.c-scrolldown2 {
  height: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.c-scrolldown {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.c-scrolldown2 {
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-scrolldown2" id="pointer-cursor">
  <div class="c-line2"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="c-scrolldown">
  <div class="c-line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i am doing the same but it applies only in one element, another element's cursor didn't change, this problem is in not in one page in another page i have similar problem

Comment: well, check the spelling of your classes in both the HTML and the CSS code.

Comment: i checked many times, i cant use different cursors on different elements, like you show in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different cursors for different elements if you want to use it.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.c-scrolldown{
cursor:pointer;
}
.c-scrolldown2{
cursor:crosshair;
margin-bottom:30px;
}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="c-scrolldown2" id="pointer-cursor">
<div class="c-line2">Crosshair</div>
</div>
<div class="c-scrolldown">
<div class="c-line">Pointer</div>
</div>
<body>
<html>
```